# MVC Controller overwrites data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have the entity `added`,`added_from`, `last_edited`,`last_edited_from` in the model `Products`. If someone creates a new `Product`, the four enumerated entities are to be filled with corresponding data; With this everything is fine. If someone is editing a `Product`, only the`last_edited` entities are to be filled, but my method in the controller overwrites the `added` entities every time and empties them.

Controller Method:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Product product= db.Product.Find(id);
            if (product== null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Category_id = new SelectList(db.Category, "Id", "Name", product.Category_id);
            return View(product);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Barcode,Name,Category_id,Comment")] Product product)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                product.last_edited = DateTime.Now;
                product.last_edited_from = User.Identity.GetUserId();
                db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Category_id = new SelectList(db.Category, "Id", "Name", product.Category_id);
            return View(product);
        }
```

Model:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public double Barcode { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3)]
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Category_id")]
    public Category CategoryFK { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Category_id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? added { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("added_from")]
    public ApplicationUser added_from_User { get; set; }

    public string added_from { get; set; }       

    public DateTime last_edited { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("last_edited_from")]
    public ApplicationUser last_edited_from { get; set; }

    public string last_edited_from { get; set; }
```

I tried about ~5 hours but found nothing what helped to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your post look like in the HTML? I bet it's overriding the values because your values aren't being passed back to the post.

You can solve this in two ways:

1. Change the HTML/Razor to include the "added" information so that when you POST, that information is included. (Not sure if this is already happening).
2. Do a lookup and find the product using it's id first and then modify the properties as normal. This is the best option because you don't really want to be passing your database objects up through to your views (and then back down to POSTs). The exact syntax for this might be off for the product lookup, but it should be close enough for you to get a general idea of what it is doing.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
   public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Id,Barcode,Name,Category_id,Comment")] Product product)
   {
       if (ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           var productInDb = db.Products.First(x => x.Id == product.Id);
           productInDb.last_edited = DateTime.Now;
           productInDb.last_edited_from = User.Identity.GetUserId();
           db.Entry(productInDb).State = EntityState.Modified;
           db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
       }
       ViewBag.Category_id = new SelectList(db.Category, "Id", "Name", product.Category_id);
       return View(product);
   }
   ```

Comment: The second one was the a good choice for me, I had already suspected something similar, but I did not really get it ... :S